# Ruby Singletion Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, singleton

I want a **HomePage** model to be a **Singleton class**, as i want only one instance of the **HomePage** model. So this is what I did:

```
require 'singleton'

class HomePage < ApplicationRecord

  include Singleton
  has_one_attached :image

end
```

In **HomePagesController**, I want the users to be able to **edit** the unique instance of the HomePage model. So, i did something like this:

```
class HomePagesController < AdminDashboardsController
  def edit
    @home_page = HomePage.instance
  end
end
```

**Problem:**

The default value that **HomePage.instance** returns **nil**. I am guessing that the instance is not **persisted**, as it returns **false** for the **presisted?** method call.

I want to be able to create the unique instance for the first time, i.e. override the nil instance that I get from **HomePage.instance** using seed data, or rails console, and then give the user the ability to edit that instance for as long as they want, using the HomePage Controller as shown in above code.

**What i tried:**

I tried updating the initial unique instance of the HomePage model, by calling **HomePage.instance.update(name: "Hello")**. This seemed to create a different instance with id:2, rather than overwriting the previous unique object.

Am I missing out on something? Or am I misunderstanding the overall use of Singleton class itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that singleton is about Ruby object, not about record in the database. And because of multi-threading the processes in Rails are isolated

So if you need to keep just one record don't use `require 'singleton'`

Define method

```
def self.get
  first || create # more Rails way - first_or_create
end
```

or

```
def self.get
  first || new # more Rails way - first_or_initialize
end
```

And in your code call `HomePage.get`

Comment: Or maybe you could implement `def self.new ; first || super ; end` and keep the singleton.